# Aligning Text in HTML using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sample

```
 text a b c d
 text2 a b c d
 text3 a b c d
```

Result should be

```
 text              a              b           c           d
 text2             a              b           c           d
 text3             a              b           c           d
```

How can I do this?  Solution may not depend on bootstrap. Just to get a view like this.

Comment: you can use `table` or `css` float

Comment: This looks like a place for the HTML `table` element. Can the question be that simple? Of course, showing some *real* content would make this easier to see.

Comment: I don't understand `I am using bootstrap. Solution may not depend on bootstrap.`

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela Sorry, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Bootstrap is just a really overly complicated, and very large, collection of styles and style patterns. If you are just starting out, you are doing your self a disservice by using it. I would recommend learning CSS positioning basics. Is this tabular data? If so, it should be in a `<table>` if it's just a fun grid, it can be floated. So, which is it?

Comment: If it’s “just a fun grid”, then Twitter Bootstrap makes it easy to get what you want, within some limitations – and this would be very basic use of TB. But if it is actually tabular data, that would be a completely wrong approach. So “which is it?” is really the relevant.

Comment: You should write out the html first. Then - once you have organize your content, you can actually style it.

Comment: Agreed that TB would be fast, until there was a problem and then the OP would be lost, especially if trying to do things responsively.

Comment: Is there any sample code that could give a guide so that I can vote for an answer. A simple code like usign tables or bootstraps. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ptwL7

### HTML

```
<table class="kenos-table">

    <th colspan="4">You could have a header if you wanted</th>

    <tr>
        <td>text 1</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>text 2</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>text 3</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>text 4</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

## CSS

```
.kenos-table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 40em;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    border-collapse: collapse; /* key - remove me to see */   
}

.kenos-table th {
    display: none;
}

.kenos-table tr {
    /* - */
}

.kenos-table td {
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: The 2 best things I ever did was look up `box-sizing: border-box;` and skip bootstrap.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

With twitter bootstrap 3

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">textA</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">a</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">b</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">c</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">d</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">textB</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">a</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">b</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">c</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">d</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/bbankes/ELamR/